# I am getting this error : type 'CastList<dynamic, String>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my model :

```
class BooksModel {
  late List<dynamic> books;
  String? bookName;
  String? bookImage;
  String? bookDes;
  String? id;

  BooksModel({
    this.bookName,
    this.bookImage,
    this.bookDes,
    this.id,
  }) : books = [];

  factory BooksModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var model = BooksModel(
      bookName: json['bookName'] as String?,
      bookImage: json['bookImage'] as String?,
      bookDes: json['bookDes'] as String?,
      id: json['id'] as String?,
    );
    model.books = json['books'] ?? [];
    return model;
  }


  List<String> get booksName => books.cast<String>();
}
```

This is my code where i am trying to pass API for image displaying in Network image :

```dart
Container(
  height:220,
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
    color: index.isEven ? Color(0xFF69c5df) : Color(0xFF9294cc),
    image: DecorationImage(
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      // image: NetworkImage("https://641ec13fad55ae01ccaf4ebf.mockapi.io/book" + "/uploads/" + popularBooks.bookImage!),
      image:NetworkImage("https://641ec13fad55ae01ccaf4ebf.mockapi.io/book/uploads/${popularBooks.books[index]['bookImage']}"),
    ),
  ),
),
```

I've uploaded my model because from there i am getting books objects .

And i've uploaded the  part of code where i am trying to display image from api using NetworkImage but facing this error.

Thank you:)

Comment: I think the error is coming from `BooksModel.fromJson` usecase

Comment: Where do you use `booksName`?  Somewhere you are trying to use that where a `Map` is expected.

Comment: booksName is used here in this line  :   _booksList.addAll(booksList.map((book) => book.booksName).toList());

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error you are getting could be because of the fromJson function.

try like this:

```
factory BooksModel.fromJson(Map json) {
final Map<String, dynamic> map = Map<String, dynamic>.from(json);
var model = BooksModel(
  bookName: map['bookName'] as String?,
  bookImage: map['bookImage'] as String?,
  bookDes: map['bookDes'] as String?,
  id: map['id'] as String?,
);
model.books = map['books'] ?? [];
return model;
```

}

Probable reason for the error: your function was expecting Map<String, dynamic>, but a Map<dynamic, String> was arriving, so just put the Map.From to do this conversion.

Comment: Heyy !! Thank you for the answer but i am still facing the same error